# What is the use of widget binding in this situation?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm reading code for a simple object detector app that runs on a real time camera feed. In the `camera_view.dart` file that handles the camera functions in the app, I found the following code in the first line of the `initStateAsync` function (this function is called after overriding `initState()`:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
```

I'm new to flutter and can't understand exactly what purpose this line serves even after looking up documentation for the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to the flutter documentation the WidgetsBindingObserver class is an Interface for classes that register with the Widgets layer binding.

you can check this link for more info [WidgetsBindingObserver class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html)